# BERTopic: add legend to term score decline

Tags: python, plotly, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I plot the [term score decline](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/api/plotting/term.html) for a topic model I created on Google Colab with [BERTopic](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/index.html). Great function. Works neat! But I need to add a legend. This parameter is not specified in the `topic_model.visualize_term_rank()` function. Only the figure title, width, height, log transformation and topics to be plotted can be adjusted.

The term score decline function outputs a plotly figure and is based on [tmtoolkit](https://wzbsocialsciencecenter.github.io/tm_corona/tm_analysis.html). So I tried to tweak it there. But I cannot load tmtoolkit in colab. Tried `import tmtoolkit` and `from tmtoolkit import topicmod` patching things together from [the reference](https://tmtoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#tmtoolkit.topicmod.visualize.plot_heatmap). I found another [colab file that uses tmtoolkit](https://colab.research.google.com/github/alvinntnu/NTNU_ENC2045_LECTURES/blob/main/nlp/topic-modeling-naive.ipynb#scrollTo=NmsLizIM4rNv) but it gave me the same error. Colab does not find [tmtoolkit](https://tmtoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topic_modeling.html). So not a problem with my file but seems to be a general issue?

Another solution is to update the plotly figure. But how? Had a ponder in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/search.html?q=figure.update_&check_keywords=yes&area=default) and tried

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

labels = topic_model.topic_labels_
fig = model.visualize_term_rank(title = 'Topic Coherence', custom_labels = True)
fig.update_legends(patch = labels)
fig
```

This throws the below error.

`TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` What does it mean? It seems illogical to me that the length cannot be computed for an integer variable.

When I omit the line `fig.update_legends(patch = labels)` it produces the figure but without the legend I need.

**Up-date 2023-12-15**
Occurred to me that maybe tmtoolkit has to be installed liked BERTopic. I was convinced it could be loaded like tm or nltk. Be it as it may, below solution works and is fast. Took less than a second in Colab to produce figure.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to update the plotly figure, knowing that `fig['data']` contains a list of scatter traces, one per topic.

Inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/blob/master/bertopic/plotting/_term_rank.py) also reveals that each trace is created with an empty [`name`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-name) and that the topic labels are set as [`hovertext`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-hovertext), so you can do the following :

```
fig = model.visualize_term_rank(title = 'Topic Coherence', custom_labels = True)

for trace in fig['data']:
    topic_label = trace['hovertext']

    # The trace name appears as the legend item for that trace.
    trace['name'] = topic_label 

    # Whether or not the item corresponding to this trace is shown in the legend.
    trace['showlegend'] = True

    # You could also override the color for the given topic, eg. something like
    # trace['line']['color'] = _topic_color(topic_label)

# And the most important obviously, whether or not to draw the legend.
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True)
```

See [`fig.update_layout(showlegend=True)`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-showlegend)

Comment: Thanks a lot! worked like a charm. Just needed to adjust the height and the width to make it all legible.